# Java return value after timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I have a function that does a computation iteratively and updates a class global variable every time (the function runs the iterative deepening algorithm). I want to find a way to do the computation and then return the global variable value after 5s to the caller without waiting for the computation to finish:

```
start computation
wait 5s
return global variable and terminate the computation function if not done
```

I tried:

```
start computation in a new thread
curThread.sleep(5s)
return current global variable value and interrupt the computation thread
```

but the thread termination is failing sometimes

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  What documentation have you read.  You need to show some work.  SO is not your research assistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like a hint then the real solution, you probably need to make it adjustable for your own needs.

```
 class MyRunnable implements Runnable{

      private String result = "";
      private volatile boolean done = false;

      public synchronized void run(){
           while(!done){
                try{
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
                result = result + "A";
           }
    }

    public synchronized String getResult(){
         return result;
    }

    public void done(){
         done = true;
    }
 }
```

And the code that runs that:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    service.submit(myRunnable);
    boolean isFinished = service.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if(!isFinished) {
        myRunnable.done();
        String result = myRunnable.getResult();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    service.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but my problem is that the check -while(!done)- is done at the beginning of the function and the function body does a heavy computation and modifies some data which I don't want to happen after the timeout. a solution to this is to check the variable 'done' at multiple points inside the function. I was thinking if there is a safe way to interrupt the thread immediately.

Comment: @Mouhyi of course there is. Just interrupt the thread and catch that. Look into javaspecialist issue 56.